# Ionic2: FCMPlugin.onNotification never seems to fire

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the [cordova fcm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase) in my Ionic 2 application. I have installed the plugin using..

```
⁠⁠⁠ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm 
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-velda-devicefeedback
```

and have added the following code into `app.component.ts`

```
    declare var FCMPlugin;
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      rootPage = TabsPage;

      constructor(platform: Platform, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
          Splashscreen.hide();
          this.setupNotifications();
        });
      }

      private setupNotifications() {
        try {
          let fcmPlugin = FCMPlugin;
          fcmPlugin.getToken(
            function (token) {
              this.log(token);
            },
            function (err) {
              this.log("error retrieving token: " + err);

            });

          fcmPlugin.onNotification(function (notification) {
            this.log("got notification");
            this.log(JSON.stringify(notification));
          }, function (error) {
            this.log(error);
          });
        }
        catch (exception) {
          this.log(exception);
        }
      }

      private log(m: any): void {
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: m,
          duration: 5000
        });
        toast.present();
      }
```

I build the app for Android and install on my Android phone.

I do not get any "not defined" errors when I run the app. I then use the [Firebase message console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) to shoot off a few messages.

If my Ionic application is closed, I *do* get the nofication on my device, and if I click it, it *does* open the app, so that part does seem to work.

However, when the app is open, I do *not* get the `onNotification` called, ever.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? Am I calling setting it up correctly?

Thanks in advance for any help!

[EDIT]

The suggestion by Jorge's answer is I need the `click_action` which you can't send via the console. So I am now trying to send via POSTMAN. The doco for this seem to be very poor, or at least hard to find everything in one place. eg what to include in the headers.

Anyway, by trial and error using POSTMAN I use the following headers..

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=myappkey
```

and I am using the following URL `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` and the following in the body...

```
    {
      "notification":{
        "title":"Notification title",  
        "body":"Notification body",  
        "sound":"default", 
        "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",  
        "icon":"fcm_push_icon"  
      },
      "data":{
        "param1":"value1",  
        "param2":"value2"
      },
        "to":"", 
        "priority":"high", 
        "restricted_package_name":""
    }
```

POSTMAN returns 200, but I get nothing on my device at all, whether the application is running or not.

[EDIT2]

I noticed POSTMAN *is* returning an error

```
        {
      "multicast_id": 5810330647165506849,
      "success": 0,
      "failure": 1,
      "canonical_ids": 0,
      "results": [
        {
          "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
      ]
    }
```

So then I tried in fiddler, and get a different error (still 200 status returned though)

```
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Content-Type: application/json
    X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 2ae6d1bccf7e610bf4c91bd7ef482b5e;o=1
    Date: Sun, 04 Dec 2016 14:43:52 GMT
    Server: Google Frontend
    Content-Length: 62
    Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"

    {"result":1, "message":"JSONObject[\"recipient\"] not found."}
```

I have also since added a token id returned from a call to getToken to the "to" field.

Any further ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying on android?

Comment: Ah yes this is on Android.

Comment: Did you set in `"to"` field a single fcmToken? I have tried many times from postman and for me it does work well.

Comment: I used the token returned by the getToken(). I tried from fiddler and noticed I am getting the following back (even though the result is 200) `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 2ae6d1bccf7e610bf4c91bd7ef482b5e;o=1
Date: Sun, 04 Dec 2016 14:43:52 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 62
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"

{"result":1, "message":"JSONObject[\"recipient\"] not found."}` So looks like perhaps something to do with a `recipient` field??

Comment: So your token is incorrect or has not been properly registered on FCM by your application :/ Try to send it to `/topics/all`, but consider it will be received by all your registered devices.

Comment: Ah, NOW I get something through (using the `/topics/all`). So it's actually something wrong with my "to". I did use the string returned by getToken() (very long string), and it didn't work using this (get `InvalidRegistration`) error. I need to read some more to see what this "to" field is meant to hold.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is out of the scope of the question. Ask another question if you like but this should be closed

Comment: @Jorge  Yes, the question has changed, but thanks for the info. I'll post a new one

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you have just forgot to add the `click_action` field to the notification. It must look like this:

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",  //Any value
    "body":"Notification body",  //Any value
    "sound":"default", //If you want notification sound
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",  //Must be present for Android
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"  //White icon Android resource
  },
  "data":{
    "param1":"value1",  //Any data to be retrieved in the notification callback
    "param2":"value2"
  },
    "to":"/topics/topicExample", //Topic or single device
    "priority":"high", //If not set, notification won't be delivered on completely closed iOS app
    "restricted_package_name":"" //Optional. Set for application filtering
}
```

Make sure you have included `"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"` as this is the intent that should be fired when clicking on the notification.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for that, this could be the problem. I am just using the notifications console from Firebase so perhaps this does not include the click_action. There is a test tool mentioned for the plug (ie https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/), but I can't get it to work. I've entered the API key as given in the Firebase project settings (Web API Key), but the tool keeps reporting `Invalid API Key`. Have you used this tool (i.e. does it work, and if so any idea why the Invalid API key)? (perhaps it includes the `click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY`

Comment: I'm sorry but you can not use firebase console for this. You can not send click_action with it. For testing you must use your own backend or some app that let you use click_action. I'm totally sure that is your problem.

Comment: Yes will accept as soon as I can verify that this fixes the issue. Currently trying to find how I can test using this `click_action`. Now trying to send via Postman (so can add `click_action`). Can get a message thru (using a totally different structure to the above), but adding the `click_action` still does not make it work. Might have to EDIT the question to add details

Comment: Actually one of the errors is in the logging code ` this.log(JSON.stringify(notification));` Old trap, the `this` is not correct as it is in a function callback